# I have painted a panel but when the program starts panel shows with delay. what should I do?

Tags: java, swing, paint, paintcomponent, repaint

I have painted a panel but when the program starts panel shows with delay. what should I do?

```
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

Image img = kit.getImage(ResourceLoader.class.getResource("wood3.jpg"));


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponents(g);

    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;

    graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, null, null);


    this.updateUI();
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Don't call `updateUI`, it has nothing to do with painting. Don't call `repaint` from within any `paintXxx` method, this will simply place another request for painting again, again and again...You should consider using `graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, null, this);`. You should consider using `ImageIO.read` instead of `Tooklkit#getImage`

Comment: 1) **Note:** `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponents(g);` Should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);`! 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, could you please give me the example link of ImageObserver done by you ?

Comment: @Sage  Not sure which one you mean (I mention it often).  OTOH I typically just say WTE 'the X **is an** `ImageObserver` so use it for the `drawImage` method'.  But if they look through [my posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a418556%20drawimage) there will be plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are calling `repaint()` inside `paintComponent(Graphics g)` function: you understand that it is going to be a recursive painting-stack(request) call. Try printing a string inside your code and set your eyes on the console.
2. Use a Thread to read the image and let the swing run in EDT using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`. That way you won't have to await your application for the image to load.
3. As MadProgrammer has suggested, use `Graphics.drawImage(x, y, width, height, ImageObserver)` function. Try to set  `this` as the Observer instead of `null`. @AndrewThompson had an example to show the usecase of `ImageObserver`. i have forgot the link however :P